# Should people not say Vidui before Tachanun?

Tags: halacha, minhag, hefsek-interruption, tachanun, viduy-confession

[Assuming that it is a hefseik and forbidden to interrupt between amidah and tachanun](http://www.hashkafah.com/index.php?/topic/62106-hefsek-in-minchah/#entry1362407), should a person who regularly recites vidui change his custom and delay the recital of vidui until later on, after the kaddish titkabeil, or even perhaps after shir shel yom (the end of davening)?

Comment: Who said vidui is a hefsek? Maybe it's _part_ of tachanun.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Just maybe?  Or certainly?

Comment: Seems from the Ben Ish Chai that it is http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40322&st=&pgnum=105

Comment: @sam - I'm having a hard time reading that page.  Which paragraph specifically denotes that *Vidui* is not a *hefseik*?

Comment: Read 5 which says vidui is said and then niflas apayim is said right after.If it.was a hefsek it wouldnt be in that order.

Comment: Thank you @sam - I think I was able to understand most of that.  So basically it is the same reason why we delay *tachanun* on Mondays and Thursdays?

Comment: As per Minhag HaGro one says the Selichos (on BeHaB and fast days) between the Amidah and Tachanun. These Selichos have the Vidui (once/thrice depending on custom) and the entire (20 - 40 minute) addition is not considered a hefseik.